# Moving from Ionic to Native (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework

I've developed an application using the ionic platform. Now I want to immigrate to IOS native using swift language. My problem is that I've stored user's authentication data in cordova localstorage. Is there any way that I can extract this data and use it again in my new version?

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIWebView and implement delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
    let jsString = "localStorage.getItem('username');"
    if let usernameValue = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsString) {
        // doing something with value
    }
}
```

May be you will have to make WebView hidden, or even remove it from UI after you get data.

**Upd**: In iOS every UIWebView is it's own instance, isolated from other instances in the same app. So you will have to keep Ionic's WebView on UI (probably hidden) and get data from it's local storage. If you will make new UIWebView then it will have it's own separated local storage.